# Does binary tree efficient in solidity? iethereum/tron network

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, tron

Does storing/searching/writing binary tree is efficient enough from gas perspective?
Let say I have node A. and new node B. node B should be placed at the first available place in the subtree starting from Node A. After that, we need traverse from node B to root node and update the count field for all nodes

Also, does any lib exist for such data structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array-like rep for Tree.

```js
mapping(uint256 => bytes32) public tree;
```

FYI: https://github.com/tronprotocol/java-tron/blob/feature/shieldedUSDT/deploy/ShieldedTRC20.sol